# Session and cookie lost when clicking a link from Gmail! Very Bizzzare

Tags: php, session, cookies, gmail

**Brief Summary**
When I click a link from gmail, the cookies and sessions are lost. But if I copy the link in gmail and paste it in a blank tab, the cookies are retained!

**Long Detail**
At [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), i set cookies and PHP session with following options:

`$myCookieSessionOptions = array(`
        `'lifetime' => (time() + 60*60*24*363),`
       `'path' => "/",`
        `'domain' => "." . "mydomain.com",`
        `'secure' => true,`
        `'httponly' => true,`
        `'samesite' => 'Strict'`
      `);`
    `session_set_cookie_params ( $myCookieSessionOptions ) ;`
    `session_name("mySessionName");`
    `session_start();`

The above is the code both on page login.php  and anotherpage.php.
On login.php when I login and set sessions, etc. the session_id() shows up as c7a9c180b767e889ad0161dc613aec41, for example.

When i access anotherpage.php in a blank tab and with some GET parameters (and my code does nothing to the session), i get the same session_id().

However, when the same link for anotherpage.php (along with the get parameters) is sent in an email, then I get a totally new session_id: 3fc7f8749ba6eb46ddd35a0db3a17589 for example.

And in the other tab, which had login.php, the session is lost, as a new session is created, obviously.

The question is if this behaviour is normal?? And this is not with gmail alone, obviously. From "anyotherdomain.com", when i click on a link to my domain, no cookies are sent!

Very weird! Is there any documentation on this behavior?

Any help will be appreciated

session auto start is Off. Checked in phpinfo

And there's no code before the above that does anything at all with the sessions

Thanks

Rajan

Comment: Some more info: used windows 10, chrome. When anotherpage.php is clicked from gmail and i keep reloading the page, with every reload, i get a new session_id(). However, if i copy paste the link and enter in a new tab and keep reloading that tab, the session_id() remains the same!!!!

Comment: Just discovered another interesting thing. Once gmail has opened the link in a new tab, if i simply click on the location bar and hit enter, then with every reload, the session_id() is the same. And in the "headers" of Chrome, the only difference I see is that when a URL is clicked from Gmail, "sec-fetch-site" is shown as "cross-site"... MDN Docs don't refer to an impact on the cookies here, though :-(

Comment: And, obviously, when I check in chrome->inspect->network and click the URL (that was initially clicked from gmail), the tabs show "no request cookies were sent" . Can't find any documentation anywhere at all on this behaviour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! If I have samesite="none", the problem disappears

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

And tested it & it works fine.

As per the doc:

Strict
Cookies will only be sent in a first-party context and not be sent along with requests initiated by third party websites.